# Interlinking websites using javascript - safe for SEO?

Tags: seo, javascript

I have a nutrition network of 20 sites which share the same hosting account, though different C class IP's.
They were interlinked and suffered a massive traffic drop after penguin.
I have decided to stop interlinking them for SEO purposes but I'd like my user to still visit them because they are in related niches.

If I display them on my site using javascript, will google penalize me still for doing a link scheme?

Comment: What makes you think that it was a result of your interlinked sites that caused your traffic drop?

Answer (score 3):

[Google can crawl javascript](https://twitter.com/mattcutts/status/131425949597179904), so encoding your links in javascript wont help. [Putting them in flash links wont help either](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72746), because google also crawls that.

I think your best bet would be to use `rel=nofollow`. According to google

> having links (even a large number of them) with rel=nofollow pointing
>   to your site does not negatively affect your site. We take these links
>   out of our PageRank calculations, and out of our algorithms when they
>   use links.

Source: [google webmaster forums](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/BNs_AOVr3M0/innRAWk-kCwJ) (said by a google employee)

That said, I don't think that what you did was a good idea. You should spend your efforts more on making quality content than on trying to game the system.

Comment: I have just discovered that Google has indexed an [`alt` attribute](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/32072/1243) on a non-linked `img` and the entire element was written to the page with JavaScript! :)

Comment: @w3d it's pretty amazing what google indexes

Answer (score 1):

You're putting way too much thought into this. Those links will be less then a drop in the bucket as far as SEO is concerned. If you want to link to your owns sites, do it the right way. Trying to game the system for something like this isn't worth the effort or the potential risk you will incur for using black hat SEO techniques to manipulate your rankings.

Comment: You did not understand what I meen. I am trying NOT to game the system. I am trying not to have my links crawled by google and thus not count for SEO. And I am looking for methods to do it.

Comment: That is the very definition of gaming the system. You're intentionally serving up different content to search engines then to users. That is black hat SEO. Period.

Comment: @webmasters see http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/790/is-black-hat-seo-on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Google always says: dont think seo, think about your users.

so use **normal links**.

if the linked pages are content related **dont** use the `rel=nofollow`

if you the content of the linked page is not related or not important use can use the `rel=nofollow`

think about the users, and the rest will follow.